# azure logic apps and ftp to azure VM on subnet

Tags: azure-logic-apps, vnet

Is it possible to connect an Azure logic app to an FTP server residing on an Azure VM that lives in a subnet under a private IP address ? I cannot, when trawling the internet, find many (-if any at all) references to anybody trialling this, although we felt it might be a valid test of a need to access sFTP under unusual network circumstances. We have such a server, initially created to act as a 'remote' development VM but accessible via another Azure VM which can connect with our on-premise network, acting as a 'jump' server.

It is not a showstopper if we cannot do this - we can, after all, set up non-private VMs to act as FTP servers. And I understand that 'private' might be private for a reason ! But I was surprised that I cannot find any definite content, from Microsoft or anyone else, that this isn't possible: it seems that the only way to engineer such connection might be through an expensive Azure Integration Account or Application Service Environment. But the hint that such connection might be possible via those additional Azure facilities has caused my organisation to investigate the possibilities via the usual logic-app connector features. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your supposition is correct.  Private means private.  You can't directly access your private VM on Azure for the same reason you can't access a private VM on an internal network.

But, all the same facilities are available.  If it's a Windows VM, you can use the On Premise Data Gateway with the File Connector.

Comment: Thanks; that's understandable - we just hoped that there might be other ways to achieve this than using App Environment or Integration Account. I'll look into what we can achieve with Data Gateway.